# Install kannada fonts in micromax funbook

Tags: android, root, kannada

I have developed an app which runs well on samsung tab, but the google translated kannada words are not rendered on micromax phone. What to do? Can't I embed the font itself in the app using typeface? Or should I root the device and install the system fonts explicitly?

Edit 1: Could anyone suggest a good kannada font that has been good?

Answer (score 0):

If your app require special fonts, then embed it in your add and set later on using `setTypeface()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, i tried installing using settypeface, but its coming as boxes but not the exact font!! Tried the font in this

Comment: if "boxes" mean squares, then font apparently does not feature characters you use. If it should work check if you got your text not broken, or the font is right

Comment: Oh okie, could you please suggest a kannada font which is complete?

Comment: Nope. I got no idea which one will work. I just answered your question why the current one does not.